# Question about off-topic flagging

Tags: discussion, support, flagging

I'd like to know if the question asked by own OP has been solved by himself and it doesn't contain any other answers from users either, is it considered as: `off-topic`>`This describes a problem that can't be reproduced that seemingly went away on its own or was only relevant to a very specific period of time. It's off-topic as it's unlikely to help future readers.`?

e.g. [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/476201/ubuntu-14-04-dvd-playback-stuttering) question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would fix the question to be correct for the next person.

Edit out the SOLVED cruft, and then post a proper answer so people can vote on it. Or tell the OP to post it as an answer if they can.

Comment: I got it. Thanks.